# Update cart on customer login in Magento

Tags: magento

I am working for updating the cart price if customer belongs to particular group.
If customer is already logged in and add product to cart,cart price is same as i have added for that customer group but if I first add the products in cart and then login the account,cart price do not get updated.
How can I update the cart on customer login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an observer that fires on customer_register_success :

```
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <yourcompany_yourmodule>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>modifyItemFinalPrice</method>
                </yourcompany_yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
```

An idea of what can be in the code :

```
/**
 * appelé lors de l'ajout au panier et à chaque fois que le panier est revalidé
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function modifyItemFinalPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $item = $observer->getData('quote_item');
    $this->_manageItem($item);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item
 */
public function _manageItem($item) {
    try {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $newPrice = $this->_calculatePrice($product);
        if ($newPrice){
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}


    /**
 * 
 * Retourne un prix en fonction des différentes contraintes du site
 * 
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return float|boolean
 */
private function _calculatePrice(&$product){
    $website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session');
    $groupeid = $customer->getCustomerGroupId();
   Your logic here...
}
```

I use a function _calculatePrice to calculate the price and for _manageitem as i need it somewhere else but everything can be done in a single function. It works good for me. You can even just get the price following the customer.